# How to see content of string in Remix in debugger? All I see is pointer address

Tags: solidity, remix

for example I want to see the content of 'b', not just the address. How do I do that?

```
contract Test {

    function myTest(uint a) private returns (bytes32) {

        bytes32 a = bytes32(a);
        return a;
    }

    bytes32 b = myTest(1234);

}
```

Comment: I think we're missing part of the story...what is mixRunes?  What are you trying to do, we might be able to help out more on that end vs debugging

Answer (score 1):

You are not seeing an "address". What you are seeing is the bytes32 representation of the string/number you entered. You could convert that to a human readable string in Javascript for example by using the web3 toAscii function:

```
var str = web3.toAscii("0x657468657265756d000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
console.log(str); // "ethereum"
```

https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3toascii